# python 3.8 can't be imported with pybind11 [windows]

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am developing python library in C++ using pybind11. The problem is that python 3.7/3.6 works well, but
python 3.8 cannot be imported. This is the error when importing the library( assume the library name is mylibrary).

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing mylibrary: The specified module could not be found.
```

Why Python3.8 can be built in pybind11, but cannot be imported ?

Comment: You need to stritcly match the python version for which your build the dll and the python interpreter you use to execute the dll. If you buils using python 3.8 you can use only with python 3.8.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your C++ python library itself depends on a shared library / DLL. Python 3.7/3.6 would search for DLLs in PATH or the current working directory, but this is no longer the case in Python 3.8:

https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#ctypes

If this is the problem, you can add use [add_dll_directory()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.add_dll_directory) to tell Python 3.8 where it should look for the DLLs.